# contact pin 1(3,3v supply) pin 6(0v ground) reboot

Tags: power, power-supply

I want to supply a circuit with these two pins. But when they contact each other my raspberry reboot.
Is my raspberry broken?

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPi.SE To provide useful help you could add more information about your problem (e.g. which is the connector those pins are connected at, what is the load that has been connected (the power drawings thereof)). It's not necessarily broken but it's hard to answer that with this little information given.

Comment: I just connect two cables. One cable to pin 1 and another one to pin 6. I Touch both cables each other and raspberry crash. I think I did it before without problems.

Comment: Ok, why would you want to short-circuit these Pins (see joans answer)? I was assuming you'd connect some circiut/load (read something useful).

Comment: I say that like a previous step. It crash also connecting dc motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing the connection while raspberry is On. I have done connection before to turn on the raspberry and even with 750 mA power supply it is working fine. Thank you joan!

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Please consider accepting your own answer as soon as you will be allowed to ([48 hours from the moment you posted your question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)). It will point out to other people that this solution worked for you :-)

Answer (score 3):

The 3.3V and ground pins should never be directly connected without a load of some sort.  You are short-circuiting the Pi causing it to crash.  You can seriously damage your Pi with a short-circuit.

What do you want to power from the 3.3V pin?

Comment: I want to power a little dc motor.

Comment: What could I do? It also crash with dc motor connection.

Comment: How much current does your motor need.  Old Pi's can only supply about 50mA on the 3V3 rail.  The B+ will supply more (I don't know how much).  By the way NEVER try to power a motor direct from a gpio.

Comment: The motor is something like that but without transistor http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=W7cV9_W12sM . I think I power it before directly with no crashing with pin 1 and another pin that is not 6.

Comment: The video uses a diode (essential) and a transistor to switch the power.  That is the minimum you will need to drive a motor AND switch it on and off from the Pi.  If you want the motor permanently running perhaps try powering the motor with a 5V pin and a ground pin.  If the motor is rated at less than 5V this will shorten its life.

Comment: When I connect pin 2 (5v) and pin 6 (ground) to motor raspberry crash. That is the matter.

Comment: Maybe the raspberry crash before I am not sure about it.

Comment: I suspect you have a marginal power supply.  I power my Pi via the 5V and ground pins with a 5V 4 amp supply.  There is plenty spare to drive motors.  If you are using the microUSB try a better cable or a better power supply.

Comment: My power supply to raspberry is 5v and 750mA. I don't undetstand that you mean with a 5v 4amp in ground pins. Have you 2 supplies connected to raspberry?

Comment: No, I just feed power in by connecting a 5V power supply directly to the 5V and ground pins.  I don't connect anything to the microUSB socket.  I suspect your 750mA supply isn't capable of supplying enough power.

Comment: I will buy another supply with 3 o 4 amp. And I will tell you. Thank you so much!

Comment: 2 amps should be enough and may be cheaper.  Good luck.